# Gitlab docker dnd build fails failed to do request

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

*ERROR: failed to do request: HEAD "https://IP:5000/v2/project/app/manifests/stg": https: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.*

I replaced all he confident information (IP, project ) where app is the name of the image that I am want to use in a dockerfile with *COPY --from=IP:5000/project/app:stg* with the paths from where and where I want to copy.

I am using gitlab on my own server and I have set insecure_registry in my .gitlab-ci.yaml file.

I am trying to figure out this problem.

I want to copy from an image file, some dependencies that I need in order to build another image file from a dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm little confused about your questions

But in my experience,

ERROR: failed to do request: HEAD "https://IP:5000/v2/project/app/manifests/stg": https: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.

This happens when you don't have https certificate for registry, So
as you said there is insecure registry setup's on .gitlab-ci.yaml

But I think insecure registry settings has to be setup at your docker **daemon.json** ( check who is Building your Image )

Find which container runtime your gitlab using and add insecure registry configuration to them

Give me more question or information on comment when this is not clear

You have to check your gitlab is